# UIActivityIndicator and GCD/Threading

Tags: objective-c, ios

i am fetching a list of photos from a server and displaying them. i'm using GCD to thread the server calls. I got it working, but i want to add in a UIActivityIndicator for each UIImageView to show that its doing something and will appear.

i'm not sure what the best method would be.

code:

```
UIScrollView *myScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width, photoView.frame.size.height)];
myScrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
myScrollView.pagingEnabled = TRUE;
myScrollView.scrollEnabled = TRUE;

myScrollView.frame = CGRectMake(myScrollView.frame.origin.x, myScrollView.frame.origin.y, (6 * THUMBNAIL_SIZE) + (PHOTO_VIEWER_OFFSET_COLUM_1 * 2), myScrollView.frame.size.height);

//get list of photos

for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);

    dispatch_async(queue, ^{
        NSLog(@"async thread %@", [NSThread currentThread]);

        //retrieveThumbnailedGeotaggedPhotoWithPhotoID will make a server call
        MyUIImageView *myImageView =  [[MyUIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[self retrieveThumbnailedGeoTaggedPhotoWithPhotoID:@"test"]];
        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            NSLog(@"main thread %@", [NSThread currentThread]);

            myImageView.frame = CGRectMake(myImageView.frame.origin.x, myImageView.frame.origin.y, THUMBNAIL_SIZE, THUMBNAIL_SIZE);
            myImageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            myImageView.position = i;
            myImageView.isEnlarged = FALSE;
            myImageView.delegate = self;

            int group = (i / 6);

            myImageView.frame = CGRectMake((i * myImageView.frame.size.width) + (PHOTO_VIEWER_OFFSET_COLUM_1 * ((group * 2) + 1)), 
                                           PHOTO_VIEWER_OFFSET_COLUM_1, 
                                           myImageView.frame.size.width, 
                                           myImageView.frame.size.height);

            myScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake((myScrollView.frame.size.width * (group + 1)), myScrollView.contentSize.height);

            [myScrollView addSubview:myImageView];
        });
    });
}
```

i'm pretty sure animating and stopping the activityIndicator needs to be on the main thread, but not sure how to include it. it needs to be animating during the "retrieveThumbnailedGeoTaggedPhotoWithPhotoID" method which is in a thread (but not main thread).

Comment: Which part are you unclear about? How to get something on the main thread? Or working with an activity indicator? You've already solved the first part -- GCD's main queue is guaranteed to be run on the main thread.

Comment: where to insert an activity indicator into the code so that its on the main thread and doesn't crash me. it seems to me the perfect place is in the async threading, but that would crash it (UI not on main thread = crash)

Comment: should i do another dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue() right before i make the server call to start animating and again right after the server call to stop animating?

Comment: `dispatch_async`, but other than that, yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

k, i re-ordered it:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
    //create the subviews first
    MyUIImageView *myImageView =  [[MyUIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((i * THUMBNAIL_SIZE) + (PHOTO_VIEWER_OFFSET_COLUM_1 * (((i / 6) * 2) + 1)), 
                                                          PHOTO_VIEWER_OFFSET_COLUM_1, 
                                                          THUMBNAIL_SIZE, 
                                                          THUMBNAIL_SIZE)];

    myImageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [myScrollView addSubview:myImageView];

    UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];

    spinner.center = CGPointMake(THUMBNAIL_SIZE / 2, THUMBNAIL_SIZE / 2);

    [myImageView addSubview:spinner];
    [spinner startAnimating];

    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);

    dispatch_async(queue, ^{

        UIImage *myImage = [[UIImage alloc] init];
        //only make the server call in the async queue
        myImage = [self retrieveThumbnailedGeoTaggedPhotoWithPhotoID:@"test"];

        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            NSLog(@"main thread %@", [NSThread currentThread]);

            //MyUIImageView *myImageView =  [[MyUIImageView alloc] initWithImage:myImage];
            [myImageView setImage:myImage];
            myImageView.frame = CGRectMake(myImageView.frame.origin.x, myImageView.frame.origin.y, THUMBNAIL_SIZE, THUMBNAIL_SIZE);
            myImageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            myImageView.position = i;
            myImageView.isEnlarged = FALSE;
            myImageView.delegate = self;

            int group = (i / 6);

            myImageView.frame = CGRectMake((i * myImageView.frame.size.width) + (PHOTO_VIEWER_OFFSET_COLUM_1 * ((group * 2) + 1)), 
                                           PHOTO_VIEWER_OFFSET_COLUM_1, 
                                           myImageView.frame.size.width, 
                                           myImageView.frame.size.height);

            myScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake((myScrollView.frame.size.width * (group + 1)), myScrollView.contentSize.height);

            [spinner stopAnimating];
        });
    });
}
```